# how do you groupby a field that contains a string

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

Facing a issue in using groupby function for data having column of strings , unable to use mean for groupby in my data its shows error as :Could not convert "string" to numeric

tried going traditional way but didn't work
unable to use mean for groupby function in pandas

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? What do you expect the mean of a string to be? If your strings are of numbers, e.g. ["10", "3"], then convert them to ints or floats first.

Comment: the csv file contains car companies there colours the distance the cars covered along with price , the column "car name" has values for example "toyota","nissan"...on applying mean in groupby to the column df.groupby(['car name']) .mean()    its gives error as  could not convert "toyota " to numeric

Comment: Thanks, you need to include that information in your question. As it stands, your question is impossible to answer. I suggest you _edit_ your question now, to include a small snippet of your dataframe (in text, not an image), the code you tried, and a hand worked example (in text) of what you expect the output to be. These three aspects are essential to any question you ask in the future. I recommend you _edit_ this question now to add them in as practice.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment it sounds like you want to group by the `"car name"` column, and then find the mean of another numeric column for each group.

When you try it your way i.e. `df.groupby(['car name']).mean()` pandas is going to try calculate the mean for *all* the columns in your dataframe aside from the one you grouped by. Since your dataframe does have other text based columns, e.g. colour, pandas throws an error as it doesn't know how to calculate the mean for colours.

To fix this, you should specify exactly which column you want to aggregate. There are many ways to do this, for example if you want to aggregate a column called price you can do it like this:

```
df.groupby("car name")["price"].mean()
```

or like this

```
df.groupby("car name").agg({"price": "mean"})
```